# What is the difference between first and second case?

Tags: c

What is the difference between first and second case, why does the first work as expected, while the second doesn't? (in the second case i am trying to introduce a pointer that dereferences the pointer to pointer, in order to avoid typing extra asterisks).

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int* test = NULL;
    foo(&test);
}
```

case 1:

```
void foo(int** ppPar)
{
    *ppPar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    **ppPar = 7;
}
```

case 2:

```
void foo(int** ppPar)
{
    int* pPar = *ppPar;
    pPar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pPar = 6;
}
```

Comment: As you tagged the question C++, why not use `void foo(int*& ppPar)`

Comment: 2nd `foo()` leaks memory.  The memory allocated is lost once the function ends.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244429/pointer-of-a-pointer-in-linked-list-append/15244654#15244654

Comment: Add `*ppPar = pPar;` as last statement to the 2nd case andf it'll work also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
*ppPar = ...
```

This reassigns the pointer `test` that was in main;

```
**ppPar = 7
```

This changes the value pointed at by `test` in main.

---

```
int* pPar = *ppPar;
pPar =
```

This makes a *copy* of the pointer `test` that was in main, and then reassigns the *copy*. (So now there is no connection to `test` at all.

```
*pPar = 6;
```

This changes the value pointed at by `pPar`, which is no longer associated with `test`.

Comment: what is reccomended way to introduce new variable to not to type extra asterix everyvere in foo (for pointer to pointer)? Or i should live it ?

Comment: @BransDs: If you want to refer to an _existing_ variable, you have to use pointers.  (C++ has alternatives, but not C)  You could use a macro, but that's generally considered to be bad form.  Use a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the main idea of your code, and simplify it:

```
int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
int y = *x;
y = 5;
```

In this code, it's relatively clear that while the value of `y` has changed, the value of `*x` has not.

In your code, you've added an additional level of indirection to everything. This doesn't change the main thrust of my point though:

```
int** ppPar = (something useful);
int* pPar = *ppPar;
pPar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Again, it should be clear that while `pPar` has changed, `*ppPar` has not.

Comment: As it stands this answer ist difficult to understand. (I do however)

Comment: @alk: That's fair. I've rewritten it some, but it still may not be clear to someone who doesn't already understand the reasoning. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

In the second example you assign to the local pointer `pPar` twice:

```
void foo(int** ppPar)
{
  int* pPar = *ppPar; /* 1st assigment */
  pPar = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  /* 2nd assignment */
```

As the 2nd assigmnent overwrites the result of the 1st assignment, the 1st assignment obviously is redundant, useless.

Then you assigen `6` to what had been allocated

```
  *pPar = 6;
```

but do not return the reference to it back up.

To do so add

```
  *ppPar = pPar;
}
```

The final code might look like this:

```
void foo(int** ppPar)
{
  int * pPar = malloc(sizeof(int));
  /* of even better: int * pPar = malloc(sizeof(*pPar)); */
  *pPar = 6;
  *ppPar = pPar; 
}
```