# Is fprintf not like printf when writing to file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io, printf

I've reviewed the documentation:

It says [here](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/file-io/intro/):

> Once a file has been successfully opened, you can read from it using fscanf() or write to it using fprintf(). These functions work just
>   like scanf() and printf(), except they require an extra first
>   parameter, a FILE * for the file to be read/written.

So, I wrote my code as such, and I made sure to include a conditional statement to make sure that the file opened:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>

void from_user(int*b){

    b = malloc(10);
    printf("please give me an integer");
    scanf("%d",&b);

}

void main(){

    FILE *fp;

    int*ch = NULL;
    from_user(ch);
    fp = fopen("bfile.txt","w");

    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("the file did not open");
    }
    else {
        printf("this is what you entered %d",*ch);
        fprintf(fp,"%d",*ch);  
        fclose(fp);
        free(ch);   
    }
}
```

Am I wrong or is the documentation not explaining this correctly?  thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you expect to happen, apart from what the quoted paragraph says?

Comment: You are "wrong" in your `scanf` use inside `from_user` (`&` should not be there) and in general memory management (pointer value is not returned to `main`). It has nothing to do with `printf` vs. `fprintf` matter.

Comment: You may want to add a newline to the file when you print.  Did you try opening the file in a text editor?

Comment: `void main()` should be `int main(void)`. If a book, tutorial, or instructor told you to use `void main()`, **find a better one**. Allocating 10 bytes for an `int*` makes no sense. You want *one* `int` object, so `malloc(sizeof (int))` would make more sense -- but the `malloc` isn't necessary at all, since you already have an `int` object whose address is passed as a parameter. Except that you don't, since you initialized `ch` to `NULL`. Try: `int ch; from_user(&ch);`.

Comment: Your `from_user` function doesn't modify `ch` -- it can't, functions can't modify their arguments (modifying a parameter only updates a local copy of the argument).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `from_user()` is not implemented correctly.

1. The pointer that you create in `from_user()` will not be passed back to the calling function. To do that, you need a double pointer, or to pass by reference.
2. In your code, you pass a `int **` to `scanf()`, while it is expecting a variable of `int *`.

#### Here's a working implementation:

```
void from_user(int **b){
    *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("please give me an integer");
    scanf("%d", *b);
}

int main() {
    int *ch;
    from_user(&ch);
}
```

#### Your File IO

That part is all fine. It's just the value of `ch` that is broken.

Comment: Even single pointer is enough right? Anyways we have the location being allocated and initialized in the function the OP's scanf() has an issue

Comment: @Gopi: If we want to edit the value of `ch`, then we need to pass the pointer to `ch`, or pass it by reference.

Comment: I meant why not do everything inside the func() and return the pointer like `int *from_user()`

Comment: @Gopi: That would be fine, as would pm100's variant. I felt that this kept to the spirit of how the original code was intended to work.

Answer (score 3):

a much simpler from_user implementation

```
int from_user(){
    int i;
    printf("please give me an integer");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    return i;
}
```

and in main

```
int ch = from_user();
...
      printf("this is what you entered %d",ch);
        fprintf(fp,"%d",ch);
```

Comment: Just add how it should be used : `int ch = from_user();` and later `fprintf(fp,"%d",ch);`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest fix to your own code, you don't need to use double pointers, just allocate the memory in main and pass the pointer to your function, like this:

1. Remove `b = malloc(10);`
2. Remove the `&` before b in scanf
3. Change `int*ch = NULL;` to `int *ch = malloc(sizeof(int));`

Done. Why does it matter where we allocate the memory? See my more detailed answer here: [pointer of a pointer in linked list append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244429/pointer-of-a-pointer-in-linked-list-append/15244654#15244654)

Oh and you should move `free(ch)` out from the else statement.